# Angular 5 downgradeModule not work in hybrid mode

Tags: angular, hybrid

I am trying to change my hybrid app from `upgrademodule` to `downgrademodule`, since the `$digest` fire too much issue.

But I found app is work well, just ng2 components does not work while all things in ng1 works fine.

I had create a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ZaIp5i20fiqH1vfBnZ99?p=info

I add the test component in `main.ts`:

```
angular.module('interestApp').directive('test', downgradeComponent({component: Test}));
```

And add to $stateProvider in `script.js`:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      template: '<test></test>',
      url: '/'
    })
```

But when I click the link -> home. nothing happened only  label stay in html.

This works fine in `upgrademodule`.

Please help me out! Any suggestions or answers are welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found out how to use downgrademodule.
If anyone have encountered same questions, please refer to this issue:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20856